# How to reference anonymous columns?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

What would be the proper way to reference these columns from the unnest operation?

```
select PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', f0_) from unnest(["2014-01-01", "2015-01-01"])
```

`f0_` which is the column display name is not reference-able it seems.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unnest_operator) you can alias `unnest`:

> For input ARRAYs of most element types, the output of UNNEST generally has one column. This single column has an optional alias, which you can use to refer to the column elsewhere in the query. ARRAYS with these element types return multiple columns

So you can call it like this:

```
SELECT PARSE_DATE('%Y-%m-%d', date) 
FROM unnest(["2014-01-01", "2015-01-01"]) AS date
```

[image]